# Large Bulk Update MongoDB - forEach() document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to make a bulk update on a `mongodb` collection with 110M documents that updates a field `_t` which is a number `{$type : 1}` of seconds since the epoch. I need to convert every `_t` in the database to `ISODate()`.

I tried a script `updateDate.js` like this:

```
var bulkOps = [];

db.siteEvents.find({"_t": {"$exists": true, "$type": 1 }}).forEach(function (doc) { 
    var epoch = doc._t;
    newDate = new ISODate(epoch * 1000);

    bulkOps.push(         
        { 
            "updateOne": { 
                "filter": { "_id": doc._id } ,              
                "update": { "$set": { "_t": newDate } } 
            }         
        }           
    );     
});

db.siteEvents.bulkWrite(bulkOps);
```

But I ran this script `mongo <connection details...> updateDate.js`, which ran for a while but did not make any updates.

Using this documentation page as a reference, I got to this point:

```
var bulk = db.siteEvents.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();

bulk.find( { "_t": { $type : 1 } } ).update( { $set: { <UNSURE HOW TO REFERENCE DOC HERE> } } );

bulk.execute();
```

But I'm not sure how to reference the document, whereas in the initial one I have a callback function on the `forEach()`.

Thanks for your help, Jared.

Comment: When you ran the script did you get any logs from the console? Which MongoDB version are you using?

Comment: I'm using `3.2.7`, and it didn't provide any output or logging, but I didn't log anything explicitly.

Comment: Building up `bulkOps` to contain all 110M operations at once is likely your problem. Try calling `bulkWrite(bulkOps)` every time it gets to 1000 elements and then clear it and build up the next 1000, etc.

Comment: @JohnnyHK `bulkWrite` will automatically split your array into 1000 item slices so this isn't necessary. Combined with passing `{ ordered: false }` as the second parameter, it will chop them and run them in parallel automatically and fairly efficiently. I just ran 50k bulk ops from a single array without a hitch. https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#execution-of-operations

Answer (score 5):

`find()` returns a cursor that is resolved asynchronously. By the time your forEach loop has finished running, `db.siteEvents.bulkWrite(bulkOps);` has already been called with an empty bulkOps array.

I don't know if running javascript inside the mongodb engine supports promises, so the easiest thing to do would be to call `find().toArray()` and then move your loop and the bulkWrite inside your callback. Something along these lines:

```
var bulkOps = [];

db.siteEvents.find({"_t": {"$exists": true, "$type": 1 }}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
    docs.forEach(function (doc) { 
      var epoch = doc._t;
      newDate = new ISODate(epoch * 1000);

      bulkOps.push(         
        { 
            "updateOne": { 
                "filter": { "_id": doc._id } ,              
                "update": { "$set": { "_t": newDate } } 
            }         
        }           
      );
    });
    db.siteEvents.bulkWrite(bulkOps);      
});
```